# Find specific strings and print

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have two files, an input file *FileA* and a reference file *RefFile*. *RefFile* contains the strings that I want to find in each and every line of *FileA*. Every string not found in *FileA* should print "*NULL*" instead.

FileA:

```
 MIN=0000;MSI=1111;FLA=2222;DAG=9999
 MIN=000;FLA=2222
```

RefFile:

```
 MIN
 MSI
 FLA
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

```
 MIN=0000;MSI=1111;FLA=2222
 MIN=000;NULL;FLA=2222
```

So far, here's my script:

`awk -F";" -v key="MSI" '$1 ~ key {$1=$1; print}' FileA`

Btw, I'm just new to shell scripting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk (complete rewrite):

```
$ cat program.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR==FNR { a[++i]=$1; next }
{
    d=""                                              # print buffer
    delete b                                          # record buffer =
    for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
        split($j,c,"=")
        b[c[1]]=$j                                    # b[key]=field
    }
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)                                 # for all Refs
        d=d (d==""?"":OFS) (a[j] in b?b[a[j]]:"NULL") # gather buffer
    print d
}
$ awk -f program.awk RefFile FileA
MIN=0000;MSI=1111;FLA=2222
MIN=000;NULL;FLA=2222
```

Comment: This is great! How about if I'll print NULL here: **MIN=000;NULL;FLA=2222**?

Comment: If you mean that the NULL is in FileA, it gets `split` to `c[1]` and if it is in the RefFile, it gets printed out. If you mean that the script just produces the text NULL (like in your expected output) you really need to provide some rule for its appearence.

Comment: Yes, but basically, I want to find whats in the RefFile in FileA, if a certain string in RefFile is not in FileA, it just print "NULL".  In this case, MSI is missing in FileA so the output for line 2 will be, MIN=000;NULL;FLA=2222. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So every keyword in RefFile should be found on every line in FileA or print NULL for it?

Comment: Yes, it should be!